# cannot get the duplication

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

On my Samsung Note4, I use the code clear content in Clipboard firstly:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) 
  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData data = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("", ""));
```

Secondly, I open the message, copy an SMS by long press.

Then, I cannot obtain the duplication by the code as follow:

```
ClipData data = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
```

But i can get the duplication in SMS edit box by long press